# php How does a "stay logged in" checkbox influence logging process?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm wondering what is happenning when a user logs in a website with or without checking a "stay logged in" checkbox.
From what I understand start_session creates a variable on the server and stores the session id on the client's browser in a cookie, destroyed when closing the said browser.
Following that reasoning, I guess that checking the "stay logged in" checkbox pushes back the expiration date by N seconds, which would be achieved by setting:

```
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time()+N);
```

In that case, I see no need to use cookies, at least for the logging process.
Am I right or awfully wrong? :)

Comment: it creates a cookie with an expiration so far in the future that it doesn't expire.

Comment: Some use sessions for one session only and cookies + session to stay in.

Comment: The only downside I can see of using PHPSESSID to stay logged in even after closing the browser is that the server will keep session variables in memory ad vitam as the garbage collector will only delete variables older than X days, X being superior to the number of days between user's connections. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have written an option like that is to create a token and store it in the database along with the user ID. I then give that token to the browser as a cookie. Anytime a page request is done, I check to see first if the user has an active session, then if they have this token cookie. If they have a token cookie, I look into the database to see if it is valid and if so create a session with that user ID.

I'm sure this is an insecure, easily breached method, however.

Comment: you mean IF($_SESSION): "OK log the user: ELSE: "check token in DB in case the user closed his browser". I would like to avoid checking in the DB for each check, do you think it is safe to store the token in $_SESSION? By that, I mean: if token in DB matches token in cookie then store token in session.

Comment: It would only check the DB if they do not have a valid session. Remember that in this context, "session" means the $_SESSION superglobal. The first check is to see if they have a valid $_SESSION indicating their user id. If they do not, it checks to see if $_COOKIE['token'] exists. Only in this situation (which is pretty much 1 time per user per browsing session) does the database get checked.

Comment: I was thinking about your solution. If the token is based on a random string and calculated after each user/pass login, then only one computer can log in at the same time. This would be avoided but maybe less secure if instead of using a random string, you use a secret string. Maybe that is what google uses to "log out all other sessions". They store a random secret string associated to the user which is only changed when "log out all other sessions" is selected...

Comment: There are kind of two parts to this...

First, my system is not limited to one computer. When a user successfully logs in with 'remember me' checked, a new string is generated and stored in the database. The previous one is not wiped so both are still active. There is an expiration date on each one (1 month), but a user can have an infinite number of these strings active at one time.

Second, in order to log out all sessions, all I would have to do is a simple SQL query that wipes out all tokens in the database for that user.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I started programming in php only 2 months ago and needed some answers concerning the session and cookies concepts and they are linked. I'm starting to understand it more now.
By the way, a [nice list](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) of guidelines for cookie-based logins.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of typical ways a "stay logged in" box might be handled...

- You could set the user's info in a persistent cookie, and look for that cookie.
- You could create some unique ID (it better be a big one...like a GUID or a hash), store it in a persistent cookie, and let that serve as auth info.

Note that most solutions don't involve the user actually *staying* logged in; they just make it so that the user doesn't see another password prompt.  Keeping the session alive and storing the session ID in a persistent cookie is technically possible, but for a site with a lot of users, that'd be quite a bit of extra space and load on the server.